# 500 internal server error on request to Node server from React client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

In my React/Node/Express application, I am getting a 500 internal server error when trying to make an API call from my client (React) to my server (Node.js). The client makes a GET request for vehicle models based on a URL parameter (GET api/carbon-interface/models/:makeid). The /carbon-interface route then makes a 3rd party API call to get the vehicle models data. In the 500 error message, I am getting a "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" Referrer Policy message. I've tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" to the headers of both GET requests, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas what could be causing this error? I am new to creating API's so I apologize for any basic errors. My code is below:

Client API call in React:

```
// When selectedMake is updated, get models data from GET /carbon-interface.
  // Then populate vehicle models dropdown
  useEffect(() => {
   const getVehicleModels = async (makeid) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/carbon-interface/models/${makeid}`, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
        });
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    getVehicleModels(selectedMake.id);
  }, [selectedMake]);
```

Server API call to 3rd party:

```
// @route     GET api/carbon-interface/models/:makeid
// @desc      Get vehicle models
// @access    Public
router.get("/models/:makeid", async (req, res) => {
  const makeId = req.params.makeid;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://www.carboninterface.com/api/v1/vehicle_makes/${makeid}/vehicle_models`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${config.CARBON_INTERFACE_BEARER_TOKEN}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
      }
    );
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`response`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema) returned by `axios.get` has no `set` method, because it is not an express response object. Therefore, your `response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` statement throws an exception, which you catch and convert into a 500 Internal Server Error.

What you probably want instead is

```js
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

but that could be better achieved with an additional middleware

```js
router.use(cors());
```

*before* the `router.get("/models/:makeid", ...)`. (See the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.)